# How to change static css file on API response in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my project i want to change the background-color and font of text. Both the properties are written in css file.
Project structure is:

```
|-myProject
|--public
|--src
|--package.json
```

All my css is written in public directory, and i have an api which give response of background-color and font. Now i want to change the properties background-color and font in css files according to api response.

Comment: Is there a limited number of options for these styles in your app or do you need to be able to accept any color/font the user throws at you?

Comment: i should be able to accept any color/font user throws.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to modify the base stylesheets, why not set these particular properties using the elements’ style attributes:

```js
const divStyle = {
  backgroundColor: /* Some color */,
  fontFamily: /* Some font stack */,
};

function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={ divStyle }>Hello World!</div>;
}
```

(*adapted from [the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)*)

Comment: but then i have to add style attribute to every component, what i want is to change properties in css file.

Comment: @rajatgalav There’s an approach [here](https://medium.learnreact.com/the-style-tag-and-react-24d6dd3ca974) which essentially amounts to creating a `<style>` element and using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML()` to apply your dynamic CSS to it. Would that be more like what you’re looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to use inline style on the elements you want to change. 
On api response -> set

const yourVar={
backgroundColor:##,
fontFamily:##
};

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer from MTCoster is the best approach. depending on the structure of your app you could use the new [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to make some sort of theme provider, so that you could pass custom styles that could be stored on your application state and that is loaded from your backend API. there are some tools that could help you integrate this feature more easily, like [Styled-Components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced).

with Styled components you culd write something like:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { YourComponentJSX } from '../somewhere'    
// Wrap the component where you need your custom styles
const YourStyledComponent = styled(YourComponentJSX)`
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;

  /* Color the border and text with theme.main */
  // using the short-if to add a default color in case it is not connected to the ThemeProvider
  color: ${props => props.theme.main ? props.theme.main : "palevioletred"};
  border: 2px solid ${props => props.theme.main ? props.theme.main : "palevioletred"};
`;

// Define what props.theme will look like
const theme = {
  main: "mediumseagreen"
};

render(
  <div>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App>
        <YourStyledComponent>Themed</YourStyledComponent>
      </App>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </div>
);
```

This way you could wrap your whole app and use custom styles saved on the app state that have been loaded from the backend and use them on really deeply nested ui components

*The code is a modification from the styled-component docs